# S3 Bad request Error during deployment to aws with travis ci .../resource.rb:134:in `rescue in exists?': Aws::S3::Errors::BadRequest

Tags: amazon-s3, travis-ci, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

the .travis.yml settings like this

```
deploy:
  provider: elasticbeanstalk
  region: 'us-east-2'
  app: "docker-travis-aws"
  env: "DockerTravisAws-env"
  bucket_name: "elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-932745336105"
  bucket_path: "docker-travis-aws"
  on:
    branch: master
  access_key_id:
    secure: "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"
  secret_access_key:
    secure: "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"
```

I don't quite understand what is the fisrt line mean, it is 'us-east-2' in both places,  don't know where should i change

```
Deploying application
S3 client configured for "us-east-2" but the bucket "elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-932745336105" is in "us-east-2"; Please configure the proper region to avoid multiple unnecessary redirects and signing attempts
No stash entries found.
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.11.283/lib/aws-sdk-resources/resource.rb:134:in `rescue in exists?': Aws::S3::Errors::BadRequest
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.11.283/lib/aws-sdk-resources/resource.rb:131:in `exists?'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-elastic_beanstalk-1.10.8/lib/dpl/provider/elastic_beanstalk.rb:101:in `bucket_exists?'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-elastic_beanstalk-1.10.8/lib/dpl/provider/elastic_beanstalk.rb:41:in `push_app'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.8/lib/dpl/provider.rb:199:in `block in deploy'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.8/lib/dpl/cli.rb:41:in `fold'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.8/lib/dpl/provider.rb:199:in `deploy'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.8/lib/dpl/cli.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.8/lib/dpl/cli.rb:7:in `run'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.8/bin/dpl:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/dpl:23:in `load'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/dpl:23:in `<main>'
failed to deploy
```

Comment: problem solved by set back to the previous version which the error was pemission denied.   and fixed that error, all things goes fine then.